# is any way to get transactionHash while call function?

Tags: solidity

I have a payment function in Solidity for example

```
function makePayment(address someAddress) external payable {
    balances[someAddress] += msg.value;
    uint256 blockNumber = block.number;
    bytes32 txHash = bytes32(bytes20(tx.origin));


    emit PaymentReceived(msg.sender, txHash, blockNumber);
}
```

i have some data in txHash but it is not a transactionHash. I have blockNumber.
How can i get correct `transactionHash`. Or if is not possible get it while function is running, can i get `transactionHash` if i know `blockNumber` ?

Answer (score 0):

The transaction hash is available on the underlying EVM layer when the transaction is being executed on a block producer node, but it's currently (v0.8) not exposed to Solidity.

Hopefully it's going to be implemented in a future version.

Comment: Yea thx, now i have a block number and i have a log in my transaction so i have to find my transaction in block and get transaction hash. had to make sure, thx Petr